# Faster way for Bitmap to Byte[] coversion

Tags: java, android, optimization, bitmap

I am not new to bitmaps nor new to java. I am trying to convert High resolution bitmaps to byte array in a loop. Please find code here:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
imageByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

When i am using the above approach I cam able to convert 5 images in 1 second. But I need it to be even faster. I tried `ByteBuffer` approach also like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
int size = bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight();
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(b);

byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

try {
b.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
} catch (BufferUnderflowException e) {
// always happens
}
```

*But this is very slow (Slower then previous) :(*

*Please, can somebody give a faster method? Guide Me...*

Comment: This question is not a copy of any other queston. It is related to optimization and finding the best technique. And I have done a pretty good research.

Comment: Hey can you share your finding. Which one you analyzed as faster so far.

Comment: @vrs first approach is better. I just figured out the more you compress the more time it takes. But the later one takes definitely much more time when compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is the right one.

But two things can happen here:

1. The image is maybe not of JPEG type, so conversion occurs, which takes time
2. The image is compressed 50%, which takes time

That aside, if it's taking some time, I doubt it could go faster (being the right solution).

Comment: I am making a bitmap from Linear Layout by calling ll.draw(Canvas) method. which compression will suit best?

Comment: +1 for guiding me but i need a little more help on this topic. I am having no clue since last 2 days and really have searched a lot.

Comment: If memory is not a concern you could try NOT compressing when handling the images, which will be significantly faster and compressing WHEN SAVING to disk or SD.But if you have a lot of images this could impact on the performance of the UI and ultimately of the device.

Comment: @sokie is just right. You can do less to speed up the process, but it WILL take some time to process and write, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You must consider the fact that the speed of processing is tightly tied to the speed of the device you are testing on( since this is tagged android I'm presuming you're using a mobile device ).

You should take a look at android developer on how to handle large bitmaps effectively  [Android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) . Since processing 5 high resolution images per second is slow to you I can presume you are having some kind of gallery or previews? If that's the case you shouldn't handle the high resolution images and should indeed take a look at the link above.

Also as a side-note your second code can be optimised this way:

```
int bytes = bmp.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] array = buffer.array();
```

Otherwise the most efficient way of copying bytes that I know is **copy()** taken from Commons-IO:

```
public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    int n, count = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I tried the first approach you mentioned. Didn't help as this approach 10x slower then the one i am using right now(compession technique). But i would go through the links once again. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

you can try as follows

```
Bitmap bitmap = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

hope it may work good for you!!

check for line bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream); it may cause problem..as you are using JPEG format with rate 50.